# Giving $1 million to 10 friends if they share their lotto tics

Tags: probability

I agree to pay $1$ million to up to ten (or $20$)friends if I hit the powerball if they agree to reciprocate should they win. How much do I increase my odds and is this a worthwhile bet? Each player must hold at least $5$ tickets.

Answer (score 1):

Your odds are improved by the ratio of new tickets to old tickets, as long as you don't care about the size of the win.  If you had $5$ tickets before you now have $55$ tickets, so $11$ times the (small) chance of winning.  $50$ of those tickets will only net you $\$1$ million

The mathematical sense of whether it is worthwhile is by expectation value.  If each friend you make the deal with has the same number of tickets as you, you are breaking even.  Each ticket you have is a chance to pay out $\$10$ million and each ticket they have is a chance to receive $\$1$ million.  Since they have $10$ times as many tickets as you, it is breakeven. From a life point of view, you might view your share of $\$1.3$ billion as no better than $\$50$ million less than that. Now you have some chance at $\$1$ million as well, so you could say it is a good thing.